# Dot Net Capable Build Servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, continuous-integration

I want to set up a continuous integration / build server for a C# ASP.net MVC project.  I'm aware of cruise control.net, what other build servers are out there and what are the advantages or disadvantages of each?

Is there any particular one that is generally considered the one to have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991071/continuous-integration-for-a-small-net-open-source-project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850631/which-continuous-integration-tool-are-you-using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259241/comparison-between-cruisecontrol-teamcity-and-team-foundation-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647621/cruise-control-net-alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are building a lot of things with Cruise Control, including MVC projects. Cruise control is the default choice. I wouldn't call it easy to use, but it will do what you need.

We are very tempted by [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html). It is much easier to use, but we'd need to shell out of the [Enterprise edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/index.jsp).

We happily abandon TFS Build (2005) a year ago. Poor support for chained builds, mysterious configuration, and licensing which made it prohibitively expensive to scale. We still use TFS for source control.

Whatever you choose, keep as much of your build process in standard msbuild files as possible. If you do, you can change your build server later.